# route - link_to url_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

Use the google-maps-for-rails and it works great!

Can I use (routes) url_path in the marker infowindow.

I use this code now

```
def gmaps4rails_infowindow
    "<a href='http://domainname/en/guide/umbrie/steden/#{slug}'>#{name} - #{city_h1} </a> <br><br>#{city_description}  <br> <br> <img src='/assets/#{slug}.jpg'>  " 
end
```

But I want to show another model in the same map, so different url's. I tried my url_path in the method, but with no succes. How can I do this?

Based on your reply I tried this

controller:

```
@json = City.all.to_gmaps4rails do |city, marker|
              marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/cities/show", :locals => { :object => city })
              marker.title   "#{city.city_h1}"
              marker.sidebar "#{city.name} - #{city.city_h1} " 
              marker.json({ :id => city.id, :name => city.name})
        end
```

partial:

```
%h1
  = city.name
```

i get this error message:

```
City Load (2.2ms)  SELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities` 
  Rendered cities/_show.html.haml (28143.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 28230ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `city' for #<#<Class:0x007fcab6bf0f08>:0x007fcab6be1080>):
    1: %h1
    2:   = city.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly you'd better use partials and declare infowindows in controller as described [here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Controller).

But well, if you really want  to use `url_helpers` in model, add this in your model:

```
delegate :url_helpers, to: 'Rails.application.routes'
```

and use it this way in any method:

```
url_helpers.root_path
url_helpers.whatever_path
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...i read the controller logic..and tried this..

@json = City.all.to_gmaps4rails do |city, marker|
     marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/cities/show", :locals => { :object => city })
     marker.title   "#{city.city_h1}"
     marker.sidebar "#{city.name} - #{city.city_h1} " 
     marker.json({ :id => city.id, :name => city.name})
  end

partial:

%h1
  #{@city.name}  


I got the error: 
undefined local variable or method `city' 

What am i doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: in the partial, use `object` not `@city` (that's what you pass in th `locals` hash). If this doesn't solve, tell me  from where the error is raised

Comment: and please edit your question next time you've a remark, will be easier to read. Simply add a comment to tell me

Comment: replace `:locals => { :object => city }` with `:locals => { :city => city }`